# Connect project to Git remote in intellij idea

Tags: git, macos, intellij-idea

For some reason I have to clone from Git remote, copy the project files in to a new folder, and then open the files in intellij-idea as a project.
After that, I need to make a connection between opened project in IDE, and remote Git Url.
I try to use VCS -> Enable Version Control Integration. But it assume all the project file as new files and add them to my local version control. I also set the url into VCS -> Git -> Remote; but no change.

Comment: The question description is not very clear for me. When you say "copy the project files in to a new folder", did you copied hidden `.git` folder? This folder containers git metadata and upstream info. To re-initialize to new git server, you should not copy the `.git` folder.

Comment: I just can't find .git folder! How can I see it in macos?

Comment: @Dai I do not want to initialize it to new git server. I want to use the same url.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is your cloned local repo folder. Have you tried to use "git status" command line in your repo folder? You should able to see the `.git` hidden folder with command line `ls -al`.

Comment: Thanks for ls -al. I just copy .git through ls -al. All the repository setting copied and worked well.